# Spinner is closed upon setting some text in CountDownTimer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, countdowntimer

I am trying to show a timer on the screen and on that screen I have a TextView and a RecyclerView.
The RecyclerView contains some Spinners.
When the `onTick()` method is executed, the Spinners are closed automatically.

Please provide any solution to this problem.

Code of my CountDownTimer

```
 public class CountDownTimerClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CountDownTimerClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {

        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        String time = String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
        mTvTimer.setText(time);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {


    }
}
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_member_enter_details);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    mTvTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);
    mTvBlockNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_block_no);
    mRlHeader = findViewById(R.id.rlHeader);

    //hit for web service. In the response i am starting timer 
    getData(Event.GET_EXPIRATION_TIME); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's closing because you're calling `setText` on another view. That may trigger a focus change which would cause the `Spinner` to close.

You may be able to avoid this by setting `focusable` to false on the TextView (via XML preferably), or calling `clearFocus()` on the TextView after `setText()`

Comment: So can we set text in Textview without getting focus ?

Comment: Good question. That may be possible. Another option may be to setText and then reopen the spinner programatically. You might also set `focusable` to false on the TextView.

Comment: I think this will not work because it is CountDownTimer

Comment: Try removing the setText to see if that's actually what's causing the spinner to close. You can replace it with log statements to monitor whether the timer is still ticking.

Comment: On removing setText every thing is working fine. Issue is with setText it is causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your label or textview's text in the UI Thread, so your code should look like

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    String time = String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -
                    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           mTvTimer.setText(time);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If he were updating it off the UI thread, it would throw an exception.

Comment: @FaisalKhan can you upload the piece of code where you inflate the mTvTimer?